# How to hide an Azure Bob SAS URL when shown in a HTML5 Video player in UI from Inspect element or from media player

Tags: azure, html5-video, media-player, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

I have a BlobStorage account with plenty of video files in it. These streaming media files are rendered by a UI written in ReactJs. As these videos should be accessed only by a limited audience, I need to find a way wherein copying the SAS URL from Inspect element or from the Media player can be avoided. I need to find a way to hide the URL from the viewer.

Comment: Simple answer is that you can’t.

Comment: Hi, @abhijeet agarwal. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You **could not** hide SAS URL.

You can protect it for specific users to use a [user delegation SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas) token. And set the URL as private.